# How to import bootstrap in vue chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

I'm using the vue cli ui to setup a chrome extension boilerplate. I've installed axios and bootstrap and I want to use them inside the extension. I've noticed that When I run the build process, bootstrap will not be bundled with the extension and I'm unable to use it's classes and grid to design the UI of my chrome extension. I have this line to import bootstrap inside the main vue coponent and this is the webpack config file. Is there a way to solve this dependency problem?

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="container p-0">
    <div class="row m-0">
      <div class="col-12">

        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="Profile" placeholder="@username">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" v-on:click.prevent="showFeed()">Load profile</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4" v-if="Feed">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import jquery from 'jquery';
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
      Profile: {
        Type: String,
        default() {
          return null;
        }
      },
      Feed: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showFeed() {
      console.log('clicked!')
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.main_app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

webpack config file:

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");

// Generate pages object
const pagesObj = {};

const chromeName = [
  "popup",
];

chromeName.forEach(name => {
  pagesObj[name] = {
    entry: `src/${name}/index.js`,
    template: "public/index.html",
    filename: `${name}.html`
  };
});

const manifest =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? {
    from: path.resolve("src/manifest.production.json"),
    to: `${path.resolve("dist")}/manifest.json`
  } : {
    from: path.resolve("src/manifest.development.json"),
    to: `${path.resolve("dist")}/manifest.json`
  };

const plugins = [
  CopyWebpackPlugin([manifest])
]

plugins.push(
  CopyWebpackPlugin([{
    from: path.resolve(`src/locales/en/messages.json`),
    to: path.resolve(`dist/_locales/en/messages.json`)
  }])
)
plugins.push(
  CopyWebpackPlugin([{
    from: path.resolve(`src/locales/zh_CN/messages.json`),
    to: path.resolve(`dist/_locales/zh_CN/messages.json`)
  }])
)
plugins.push(
  CopyWebpackPlugin([{
    from: path.resolve(`node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`),
    to: path.resolve(`dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`)
  }])
)


module.exports = {
  pages: pagesObj,
  productionSourceMap: false,
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: plugins,
  },

  chainWebpack: config => {

    if (process.env.npm_config_report) {
      config
        .plugin('webpack-bundle-analyzer')
        .use(require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin)
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit `index.html` in your `public` folder.
Copy and paste the bootstrap cdn link into your head tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
```